# C++: GetAsyncKeyState() does not register key press immediately

Tags: c++, sleep, keypress, getasync

In the program I am writing when I hit the 'escape' key, I want it to register immediately, even during the sleep period. Currently it waits until the end of the sleep statement before registering the key press. The sleep time is important to the program, so it is not a matter of just adding a pause and waiting on user input.

```
int main()
{

    bool ESCAPE = false; // program ends when true

    while (!ESCAPE) {
        // Stop program when Escape is pressed
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)) {
            cout << "Exit triggered" << endl;
            ESCAPE = true;
            break;
        }

        Sleep(10000);
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: To clarify, the reason for the sleep is that I am performing an action repeatedly on a time interval.

Comment: Why are you sleeping for 10 seconds? Is it because you want to perform a certain action every 10 seconds?

Comment: Yes, I am performing an action every 10 seconds

Comment: @Grehgous then use a timer instead, especially a waitable timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sleeping for 10 seconds, you can check if 10 seconds is passed, and do whatever needs to be done at that point. This way the loop is checking constantly for a keypress.

```
#include <chrono>
...
auto time_between_work_periods = std::chrono::seconds(10);
auto next_work_period = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + time_between_work_periods;

while (!ESCAPE) {
    // Stop program when Escape is pressed
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)) {
        std::cout << "Exit triggered" << std::endl;
        ESCAPE = true;
        break;
    }

    if (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() > next_work_period) {
        // do some work
        next_work_period += time_between_work_periods;
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
}
```

Comment: That loop will continue to eat CPU cycles thereby causing high CPU usage. Why not insert std::this_thread::sleep_for with a specific duration?

Comment: @Asesh What is the benefit of std::this_thread::sleep_for instead of just calling sleep() before each check between now and next_work_period?

Comment: @Grehgous if you use the first one then your code will be portable, Sleep is  a Windows API but if you are just targeting Windows then you can use Sleep

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yes I did but what if the user doesn't press any key for a while?

Comment: @Asesh: Then why did you suggest reverting the code to exactly what he was doing in his question, which was causing the problem?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I have reduced the sleep duration. Anyways, I don't have permission to rollback the changes which I was planning to do. Thanks

Comment: @Asesh: I didn't notice your attempted edit. So you mean inserting a small sleep (on the order of several milliseconds, short enough to keep the program responsive, but long enough to give the CPU some rest) in addition to checking if 10 seconds has passed? Yes, that is a good idea. I've approved your edit.